# Samsung smart TV app: How to achieve Page transition effect

Tags: samsung-smart-tv

Is it possible to have smooth page slide transition on my Samsung smart tv app ? Not just image slider but full page slider.
It seems there is no api support for that.

The following picture shows what I am trying to achieve.

If I press right arrow the page 3 must be shown with a smooth slide transition effect from right to left.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Here is the example - how to implement it from [Samsung TV developers forum](http://www.samsungdforum.com/Guide/ref00006/common_module_transition_effects.html)

You register the functions:

```
ImageViewer = new CImageViewer('Common ImageViewer');

ImageViewer.setFrameArea(0, 0, 960, 540);
ImageViewer.setOnBufferingComplete(function() 
{
   alert('Image ready!');
});

ImageViewer.setOnRenderingComplete(function() 
{
   alert('You can prepare next image!');
});
```

Start your slideshow:

```
ImageViewer.startSlideshow();
```

Play the image and prepare the next one:

```
ImageViewer.play('$WIDGET/picture_1.jpg', 640, 480);
ImageViewer.prepareNext('$WIDGET/picture_2.jpg', ImageViewer.Effect.FADE2);
```

and end slideshow:

```
ImageViewer.endSlideshow();
```

It is helpful for you to visualize the cycle of this after Rendering complete:

```
Rendering complete -> prepareNext -> Buffering complete -> showNow -> Effect -> Rendering complete
```

Comment: Hi MikroDel, This is helpful for image but I need to slide the entire html div block. I think it is not possible by your code.